# Matplotlib's inset_locator with inverted axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, insets

I want to make a standard inset into my plot. But I don't get how to use the `inset_locator`.
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes, mark_inset

x = np.linspace(0, 2)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))

ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_yaxis()
axins = inset_axes(ax, width='40%', height='30%', loc='lower left')
x_in = np.linspace(1.25, 1.75)
axins.plot(x_in, np.sin(x_in))
axins.invert_yaxis()
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4)
plt.show()
```

And the result is:[image]

Apparently it the edges connect the wrong corners. How do I get them right, when my axis goes from maximum to minimum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the `mark_inset` cannot cope with inverted axes. So you need to set the locations of the connectors manually.

```
patch, pp1,pp2 = mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=1,loc2=1)
pp1.loc1 = 1
pp1.loc2 = 4
pp2.loc1 = 4
pp2.loc2 = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Note for anyone running this interactively and confused why changing the locations doesn't do anything- you may need to add a `plt.draw()` after setting them to redraw the lines.